# Passing drop-down menu variable in URL to form

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way to pass variable information through a url and have it pre-populate a drop down menu (selected) on a contact form?

I have a contact form in which I would like to have unique urls that have a particular department prefilled. The user can still change it, but this gives them a starting point so the question can go to the correct person.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some basics here but I'd do something like:

```
//Current URL = mycompany.com/contact/hr
//This is the template 'contact'
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <select name="department">
    <option value="hr@company.com" {if segment_2 == "hr"} selected{/if}>HR</option>
    <option value="dev@company.com" {if segment_2 == "dev"} selected{/if}>Development</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Obviously you'll have other stuff in for template but the if statement is where the selection 'happens' - if nothing in the URL at segment 2 then it will be default.